# Mockito v3 chained method with entitymanager

Tags: java, mockito

in the source to be tested entitymanager is being used like:

```
entitymanager.createQuery("the sql", MyClass.class).getResultList();
```

In the testing code

```
EntityManager em = mock(EntityManager.class);
when(em.createQuery(anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any(MyClass.class)) // on the ArgumentMatchers.any(MyClass.class) I know it needs to be a Class<T> where T is a MyClass but unsure how to get it there.
```

next is the thenReturn()

I want to return a TypedQuery

seems like this cannot be done with

mock(TypedQuery.class) as a type safety warning pops up

Seems like it works with the annotation however. Is there a way with mock()?

Just to add:
got it to work with an Object

in the test class

```
EntityManager e = mock(EntityManager.class);
TypedQuery<Object> tq = mock(TypedQuery.class); // type safety warning .. how to fix?
when(e.createQuery(anyString(), any())).thenReturn(tq); // how to get a Class<MyClass> ??
when(tq.getResultsList()).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Object>());
```

still stuck on how to mock the TypedQuery to a `TypedQuery<MyClass>` and any() to return a `Class<MyClass>`

Comment: what is the point of testing db layer with mocks? use proper integration tests for that

Comment: Management wants higher code coverage

Comment: ouch. well - again, don't use mockito as it makes no sense - use any framework for integration tests with h2 driver